# Gwt 1.6 in Intellij Idea 8.1

Tags: gwt, debugging, intellij-idea

I'm try configure gwt app for debug in Idea.
Seems there is no native support in Idea, so I try configure "Java application" manually.
I'm set:

```
Main class: com.google.gwt.dev.HostedMode
Vm parameters: -Xmx256m
Program parameters: -startupUrl test.html ru.shirtmaker.Test
Check to use classpath from current module.
```

But when I run app, get 404 error in hosted browser. When I see at generated directory structure, there is no needed test.html and other files.

Could somebody help with issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the war path being posted by newer IntelliJ is /Users/myuser/Library/.... etc.  It's just plain wrong.  There is no war there.

To fix it, do the following:

- Edit Debugging Configurations
- Add your GWT debugging configuration
- Under Dev Mode parameters, add the following:

  -war /Users/myuser/source/MyGWTApp/war

This will override the one being passed in by IntelliJ to point to your dev folders.  I'd like it to be either a relative path, or use an IntelliJ variable to use the current project path - I haven't looked into this yet.

Answer (score 0):

In the Facets section of the Project Structure set the option 'Package generated files into Web Facet' to the Web Facet used by your project and it will find it.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to jump on [IntelliJ 9 Early Access Program](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/IDEADEV/Maia+EAP). In this release there will be GWT 1.6/1.7 support. I've been using it for a couple of months and it seems fairly stable.

Comment: Same problem persists in IntelliJ 9.0.3 even though there is added support.